# Watering system that measures trunk diameter

Tags: watering

I once saw a TV show in which they were featuring a vigneron who created a system whereby there were little tubes that wrapped around the trunk of each vine and they exactly measured the perimeter of the vine. So, when the vine was hydrated, it would swell, and when it was dry, it would shrink and the little tube could measure that. Then he had an automatic water delivery system that used the measurements to deliver the needed amount of water to the vine to keep it happy.

Is this a system or watering technology which is generally available, and if so, what is it called?

There are various methods of measuring trunk diameters, typically with a device called a [*dendrometer*](https://edaphic.com.au/products/dendrometers/). Also, there are newer sensor types called "[magnetoelastics](https://cordis.europa.eu/article/id/132855-two-types-of-sensors-that-provide-information-on-vineyard-water-status-are-designed)" which is the type of sensor that I think I saw in the show.

Comment: Never heard of such a system. Further, it feels just incredulous that such a system may exist. Vine trunks are not enough soft that its diameter would change based on availability of water in the soil. Further, trunk of any living tree is always hydrated, and noticeable drop in capillary pressure is not likely to happen outside of the plant dying. Further, if a system can be at all made to detect the minute change in pressure and viscosity of capillary fluid, it will be so sensitive so as to be delicate, and hence unsuitable for a rough work like irrigation.

Comment: @joy I have updated the question to include links describing dendrometer technology.

Comment: Wow thank you! I learned something new.